# Largest number using 1, 2, 3, 4

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Find the largest number using digits 1,2,3,4.
Allowed operations are addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, exponents, brackets and decimal point.
No other digits besides one of each of 1, 2, 3, and 4 are allowed.

Comment: Concatenation allowed (e.g. $43^{21}$)?

Comment: What kind of operation is "decimal point"? Division by 10? Concatenation with a decimal point in between?...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My answer is

> $\large{.3^{-.2^{-.1^{-4}}}}$

which is approximately equal to

> ```
> 8.2868580201393671 × 10262086317397329836950303705682257163703149058949801218729493738441081598107528212748648366556650639675637494834651527009111141529869553576563913474335144955245264754635782473137984138347137952222638587964313205619452868837383718224634189273547166482909758564678494081744342572499686332340283615712581599021968814570900261444208208929835178424692667808106080151784111892423283390244145242205430052948581301571055543827374667243547881546403168164256188568714616762528088966293537298281238136576979323677929910645315459531637368751080803173205102267159826018600957959640410062625909165800472087302204963540888240564840302750650240671426732699878134259276410912317928891377617777223758778463382382989565963629022860722966911068954608859273028192166051552188580748979849856353251278350155772482582741438334143652808512554106991133426578977315310016893382680601367236364084069749470853443372254750811042507482354057432410918072658245044727765974298088591966668845706028688485051186137975830957602719621770168245055731886715877988832778550404172876713201400626562113916859758503503572420850070382232653128175849958311906700033232287139899003408154625886599216875941009235625509735126594114998258345932048819865655098527930205860927170520898038642117761923498823378971868312904039581254514465902510080892393070829681344739389363741514397040092807009060910726875881384453141825033744104371971395737958626485122501355695379269195842561891300017940444007250843146820361922480751344116392255182941972803187740676380024972345500168720227172189949951860691398299398246182652471366029534374277502048202948135938069081003223661885217857165791753402969255926344169840499123321398708367849182966199587193351349701644514591422555770850315692644641571136329357676395384520945095819221313693113684815506633593297676946168808642863322194517958045547364131780483725049561364697828657935781222305378834189377105661966377091045314454118991031173193087912526897924892725160951529275788563515672220734346956396124580755195580737457208360330881698151150791281872981262824377757789388341314980234145096156743757137201608490271854073822699451807255412734980722522303923139699762630368196630273552286404778994356367186061509595169377391573831369366134581576852453834993464418486217647419063673896681944867898325972456231118592156982127682613245205919782212425302910167840826741063795872684191799995638895308957306891473710500615210723412961659166781986309014404583165906231102152376490342694958370772428651943018869371546229938417838030831640879222189814068049552852589928907904591512743620040242808226590755531639440474663587641583800442621697554893546303902475959432324564759328308633824603584364339546342426161944332919172661328751080766229426908974593575585594168751064122788288092970253110658025684620997932513513219016668348297372724670250463149737295309424720786806708373124828283533811649602811031549933077505719956123312473154763822358203354801083985391411380608647780315375184717889256426123881207826390856345667111087689549622297407014462564174827119086347075989403507398000446125814552260075930162803405191806571447051409515497234495906016852549900173449556022389261758330267597204479791260583751907084710023809663361150126798564574057651142063002126991201159541621775747453943960587843516042014061406344966241606812930445217144682486086239368164217096006694745966605077509824323316797350950803804890505252234540221261101717910889591913189012339997477799796213987139095979757436145623547701243809793324172469809035704392769537488590959754389766183420932857901554122280925066746908599401937569816742285545111251592218253108111831727236692103860359621084009490388877562290554929571984362562733488627462231557530889105022573563269755733906859490935411758586806725925566105583558406294236768213439681427435576356791496700020362584018145112514239866314523702612468426799243565874008251179795267820537055010513171904177107071953525134844444495085869067400340417014939117577063323464811135473991684188389774661885570535165414453111905051057117762104024480560427545927774193983919296047749377009310095034445970086509219765655517182047636586898443029903574234907473202661011203519378243032135094498673114416728146832596419034385663347357286813384988802936465607518179263898564670830743534635557764445817221560926548683524064281301373916413742068383589904430799748515969511038139397752962623760591119565128466028587643663877607033547466074995287085501250361046627570403743516803756281175571424646751675075355430905311392812384858796465341180927564728230634864747358694779915237032894025096970602371119193145800691274104728239715968069577401427649972875251086212443501572694123978428610616687291266725924118089529191570893750730572913152468572735797013293401548799051887549891469843057650306642160835888005379626809823311046391271689708582581786934263545271733175792982830583146160684634782026649400081657564243160252661053564861475565803077758704474992854774551586087323115312658624598321291437604178283274755573428740068102992042469934397053699399101981821335068607223415848562736332181234163823637101583933379544760705182720254328728855929802480966343843038730682669036318565947032347132480266960760212224585892883430573813441300900393490420196944322150292816339562785581710774374405951533436102041940514920175391437138957198377507432485151084771662502213556842039872772869402189286108250827388812376641082424699924056799953688097484143563580661681665090199034432581305718286046370727352310428980483442863698295838444678162603956872707672090337142987462861572455017406776634167819204750450275014013314616427798257187784140636086610841675719307416844860024962012805792708220598973909966351658496116212950967811900195584203886443349118174509186009598866023812404566944755687630488526466906459286344989197324551550838713686837000494880954251127891396585348022329867252736515009125102581898635711727987075271957476336839910426448801079659595572080173867315695789193139602623783526986709363458967575393453038979209898602810549149748342992398209171634000593553337709809924387703661350497174059539051424465341091765834005754316328157119171193430939418798285763841841342703877019088833117493399675628961828118020154003179834205271296495195424061337690158159076912390817153729108777477044881898967960755005542454728625547788938414932385939675027867347404285193605493150361963663458098942306312305045463749732110178660476632100360595221063033351145026420887319278232407800857305895900151986620657940231577015953805160224495568959694773472003123082020164997346486815010640694126853615556814660978925971027243086781330014313175470395381973366600001901892614165953743752166113769545226887009638697761924898626887270622176946526115776965143570387623290385518435560413107341098952588081314382750314761660040803109467910493108892201917644912969279136292346432514092631270940261553763876594905792408796128088804513077170050614072545933280818798163894155516861094216658342247999221150471192185848196913397474821106037462358766664418137
> ```
>
> The r.h.s. exponent has $6990$ places
>  meaning the value itself has more than $10^{6989}$ places.

Comment: Subtraction is allowed but I don't believe making negative numbers is equivalent to subtraction as there is no zeros permitted.

Comment: @TakingNotes I'd argue that -x is subtraction from an implied 0 which would appear to be perfectly legal, but ultimately OP will have to clarify.

Comment: Normally I'd say the same but the OPs insistence on no other digits makes me think otherwise. Hopefully OP does get back to us on this matter though.

Comment: Yes this solution using -x is allowed as explained by Albert.Lang. However I totally agree with TakingNotes, it should have been claried in the question itself.

Comment: not sure whether the exponent is interesting enough to be written in full... i'd just write it as ~$10^{10^{6989.42}}$ ([source](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=log_10%28log_10%28.3%5E%E2%88%92%28.2%5E%E2%88%92%28.1%5E%E2%88%924%29%29%29%29))

Answer (score 6):

I believe the largest possible number is:

> 115,792,089,237,316,195,423,570,985,008,687,907,853,269,984,665,640,564,039,457,584,007,913,129,639,936

obtainable by:

> $2^{4^{3+1}}$

Comment: Why not 31 instead of 3+1?

Comment: The OP did not include concatenation as an allowed operation.

Answer (score 4):

If concatenation allowed it is of the length of about 1.09795×10^19 decimal digits:

> $2^{3^{41}}$

Answer (score 4):

My answer is

> $\infty$

obtained from

> $\frac{2}{(4 - 3 - 1)}$

Comment: But this is not a number :P

Comment: @ACB this is a festive answer.

Comment: 2/0 is undefined, not infinity - if $a=\frac{2}{0}$, multiply both sides by 0: $0 \times a = 2$ - it cannot possibly be infinity because even for infinity, $\infty \times 0 = 0$

Comment: @somebody multiplying $\frac{2}{0}$ by $0$ gives $0$, not $2$. Multiplying anything by $0$ gives $0$.

Comment: @WeatherVane right. but here we're assuming it cancels out the $0$ on the denominator, instead of being multiplied with the numerator - which should be equivalent

Comment: It is dividing $0$ by $0$ which is really undefined. Is it $0$ or is it $\infty$?

Comment: $\infty \times 0$ is not $0$, it is undefined.

Comment: The actual problem with this answer is that it is just $\infty$, not $+\infty$. Because there is no consistent way to make "2/0" different to "-2/0" (You'd need a signed zero -> $2/+0=+\infty$). A non-signed $\infty$ is not larger or smaller than any "normal" number, they simply cannot be compared. So, claiming this is the largest value that can be formed makes no sense at all.

Comment: @FlorianF In math, we call $\infty \cdot 0$ an indeterminate form.

Comment: I mean the value of $\infty \times 0$ is undefined.